# Convert columns to rows by groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this

```
Chennai
6200SqFT
10,000 Population
Mumbai
5000sqFT
17,000 Population
```

I want to convert like this

```
Chennai    6200SqFT    10,000 Population
Mumbai     5000SqFT    17,000 Population
```

Comment: I am thinking to apply For Loop. But not getting the right flow

Comment: My entire data in in single column. I want three cells, three cells etc to go to three rows

Comment: Thanks for response. Kindly share code, if available. Pls

Comment: @BALAJIR is it solved?

Comment: No. Showing Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can below approach:

Assuming your dataframe looks like below:

```
print(df)
                   0
0            Chennai
1           6200SqFT
2  10,000 Population
3             Mumbai
4           5000sqFT
5  17,000 Population
```

---

Solution with [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
output  = pd.DataFrame(df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1,3))
#or output  = pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.reshape(-1,3))
```

---

Output:

```
         0         1                  2
0  Chennai  6200SqFT  10,000 Population
1   Mumbai  5000sqFT  17,000 Population
```

Incase you have uneven lines (not a multiple of 3, try):

```
output = pd.concat([g.reset_index(drop=True) 
         for _,g in df.groupby(df.index//3)],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

Comment: @BALAJIR replace 0 with the original column name so try `pd.DataFrame(df['original_column_name'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,3))`

Comment: This logic worked for me. Thank u very much.    

output = pd.concat([g.reset_index(drop=True) 
         for _,g in df.groupby(df.index//3)],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below,

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3), columns=['town', 'area', 'population'])
df_new.show()
```

Output

```
    town     area           population
0   Chennai 6200SqFT    10,000 Population
1   Mumbai  5000sqFT    17,000 Population
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2771 into shape (3)

Comment: I think you have missed one element. Ideally, the row count should be a multiple of 3. check where you have missed one element.

Comment: In my original data, I have 2,700 fields in single column & I want it to reshape it into 9 rows each

Answer (score 0):

try this as someone mention using slicing in comment earlier

```py
>>> a,b,c = df[::3].values.reshape(-1), df[1::3].values.reshape(-1), df[2::3].values.reshape(-1)

>>> pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}, index=range(len(a)))
         a         b                  c
0  Chennai  6200SqFT  10,000 Population
1   Mumbai  5000sqFT  17,000 Population
```

Comment: Other answer should work but gave answered as you getting error with that...let me know if you will have any issue with this

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (923) into shape (924)

Comment: Actually my data consist of 2700 Fields in a single column.  I want each 9 fields below to go to rows

Answer (score 0):

output = pd.concat([g.reset_index(drop=True) 
         for _,g in df.groupby(df.index//3)],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)

Posted by anky_91

Comment: you should just accept my answer by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer it worked instead of answering the same :)

Comment: Sure. Sorry, don't know the procedure. I will do it. Thanks Once again

Comment: no problem please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)